# Mesos DCOS offer declined on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I created a DCOS setup on AWS using [default config](https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mesosphere.io/dcos/stable/cloudformation/single-master.cloudformation.json)

I add two kafka brokers using CLI

```
(DCOS) PS C:\DCOS> dcos kafka broker list
brokers:
  id: 1
  active: false
  state: stopped
  resources: cpus:2.00, mem:8192, heap:1024, port:auto
  failover: delay:1m, max-delay:10m
  stickiness: period:10m, expires:2016-03-22 15:58:51-04
```

When I start broker I see that offer from master was declined

```
I0322 20:56:38.954476  1316 master.cpp:5350] Sending 2 offers to framework d8c03032-ebab-4c88-80cb-e2de92e3c4c4-0001 (kafka) at scheduler-fff6da19-e31e-4518-864e-2dfcdc31a5d2@10.0.3.104:53766
I0322 20:56:38.966846  1320 master.cpp:3673] Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ d8c03032-ebab-4c88-80cb-e2de92e3c4c4-O7389 ] for framework d8c03032-ebab-4c88-80cb-e2de92e3c4c4-0001 (kafka) at scheduler-fff6da19-e31e-4518-864e-2dfcdc31a5d2@10.0.3.104:53766
I0322 20:56:38.967591  1319 master.cpp:3673] Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ d8c03032-ebab-4c88-80cb-e2de92e3c4c4-O7390 ] for framework d8c03032-ebab-4c88-80cb-e2de92e3c4c4-0001 (kafka) at scheduler-fff6da19-e31e-4518-864e-2dfcdc31a5d2@10.0.3.104:53766
I0322 20:56:40.043771  1318 http.cpp:512] HTTP GET for /master/state-summary from 10.0.6.116:60000 with User-Agent='python-requests/2.6.0 CPython/3.4.2 Linux/4.1.7-coreos-r1'
```

I'm not able to find any relevant logs on the slaves to see what is going on.
/var/log/mesos has some files with no relevant info. As per the doc I should see syslogs in /var/log/messages but I don't see that file. The default config provisions CoreOS. I tried **journalctl** command but didn't find anything there too. Not sure how to debug this.

Comment: What does `dcos service log kafka` give you?

Comment: I recreated my setup and now I'm not even able to start kakfa service. I've created a new [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182864/mesos-dcos-doesnt-install-kafka) for this